# R histogram, find range of x-values by y-value (frequencies)

Tags: r, histogram

I have a list of values. With that I am actually not plotting a histogram, but returning a list of breaks and counts:

```
hist(loc$position, breaks=100000, plot=F)
```

Now I am trying to get the range of x-values, that are taken together into one bin. I am only interested in the bin with the maximum frequency. I therefore create

```
x <- hist(loc$position, breaks=100000, plot=F)
```

Now I am using that to return the middle of the bin as x-values with the max. frequency:

```
x$mids[which.max(list_histo$counts)]
```

But how do I get the full range of that one bin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hist_data <- hist(loc$position, breaks=100000, plot=F)

c(hist_data$breaks[which.max(hist_data$counts)],
  hist_data$breaks[which.max(hist_data$counts)+1])
```

This way you will get a vector with the begin and end values of the bin with most elements.